# Basic MongoDb Retrieval

Tags: mongodb, find

I have two "documents" that I inserted into my MongoDB database.

```
questionsList.insert({question: "When was the War of 1812", answer: "1812", answers: ["1811", "1812", "1813", "1814"]})

questionsList.insert({question: "What year did the US land on the moon?", answer: "1969", answers: ["1969", "1970", "1971", "1972"]})
```

I simply want to access the answer value from the second document. I have been reading the documentation and it doesn't seem to work. I can retrieve the answer value from the first document without issue: `var str = questionsList.findOne({}, {question: 1}).answer;` I presume that since I am using `findOne` I can't find any other matches. The problem is that I can't seem to pull up the second document and its corresponding answer. I have tried many different ways:

```
questionList.find({}, {answer: 1})
questionList.find({answer: 1})
questionList.find({}).answer
```

My ultimate goal is to compare this answer with one of the click one answers from `choices` What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your scenario correctly, you are trying to retrieve a document based on the document index (Which is not the right thing to do, since MongoDB does not store documents in specific order).

The reason why `findOne` works is, because it just returns the first document in your collection.

What I believe you should do instead is retrieve the answer based on the question. 
Something like:

```
db.questionsList.find({question:"What year did the US land on the moon?"},{answer:1})
```

**Update:**
In the case of meteor.js

```
questionsList.find({question:"What year did the US land on the moon?"}).fetch()[0].answer
```

The reason whey we need to give [0] is fetch() returns an array of objects. (Since there can be multiple documents with same key)

Comment: that seems to point to the right document. But I am looking for a way to reference the value of the answer, not the entire object. I should have mentioned that I am also using meteor. If I add fetch, that still refs the entire object.

Answer (score 0):

The final step is:

```
questionsList.find({"question": "You are human"}, {"answer": 1}).fetch()[0].answer
```

We are treating it as any other object (i.e. the first within a list of objects and using dot-notation)